# SCR drop voltage

Tags: opto-isolator, scr

unfortunately there is a voltage drop for the SCR , as I used an opto with a single SCR , when I checked the open anode cathode voltage without any load it was about 5V instead of 12 volts, when I add a 10Ohms load between anode and cathode the voltage on the load was about 1 volt ( instead of 12 volts) I would be grateful if you help me. 
thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but your text is a mess with lack of capital letters and punctuation and your diagram is too. There is a built-in schematic tool with a button on the editor toolbar. Please fix if you wish us to take you seriously.

Comment: Is pin4 of the Opto connected to the cathode of the SCR anywhere?

Comment: @JonRB yes , I have checked it not connected but still the problem has reminded

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @ashkansed an SCR requires a gate-cathode current loop to facilitate an anode-cathode conduction. If you gate circuit does not have a cathode connection it will not be controllable as expected (if at all)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with your schematic.

1. There is no load on the SCR. When it turns on it will short-circuit your 12 V battery.
2. There is no ground reference between the two circuits so there is no return path for the SCR trigger current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSQicS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. SCR trigger by opto-isolator.*

- Add in the red line shown in Figure 1.
- Move the transistor to the +5 V. Now when the opto-isolator is turned on the SCR gate will be pulled high and it will turn on the SCR.

**Trigger current and voltage**

[image]

*Figure 2. Trigger characteristics for the [BT151-500R](http://www.tme.eu/en/Document/318c350090464f181d6ad02118d9d60e/BT151-500R.pdf).*

[image]

*Figure 3. [Vishay 4N32, 4N33](http://www.vishay.com/docs/81865/4n32.pdf) \$ V_{CE} \$ saturation voltage.*

Since the emitter of Q1 may be as low as 4 V when turned on and the SCR gate trigger may be as high as 1.5 V that leaves us with 2.5 V to drive 15 mA into the SCR gate. \$R_{2max} = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {2.5}{1.5m} = 167~\Omega \$. Set R2 to 150 \$ \Omega \$ for reliable operation.

Comment: Unless the opto is PNP, this won't necessarily work. The voltage at the emitter can only be as much as Vb - 0.7ish so you're not going to pull to 5V.

Comment: I don't know if \$ V_b \$ is relevant in an opto but you did force me to do another 15 minutes work to get the details for worst case. I've dropped R2 from 220 \$ \Omega \$ to 150.